# android:syncable=true for a ContentProvider?

Tags: android

While trying to understand Android's `SyncAdapter`/`ContentProvider` framework, one thing still eludes me. I don't understand why a ContentProvider needs `android:syncable="true"` to be defined in the manifest.

Why does a `ContentProvider` need to know if it will be used from within a `SyncAdapter`?

The Google docs say:
"The flag allows the sync adapter framework to make data transfers with the content provider, but transfers only occur if you do them explicitly."

Does that mean that if I don't specify `android:syncable="true"`, I can't use the `ContentProvider` in the `SyncAdapter`'s `onPerform`? If so, how can the framework even enforce such a thing?

Can someone help me shed some light on this subject?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ContentProvider won't show up in Data & Synchronization area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619101/contentprovider-wont-show-up-in-data-synchronization-area)

Comment: So you're saying that without `syncable=true`, nothing will appear in the Accounts area? I tried explicitly setting it to `false` and it's still there...

Comment: Good question, wondering this myself.

Comment: If set to `true` , you don't have to call `setIsSyncable()` in your code. They are the same, its like a switch that allows for data transfer, but the transfer part will still have to be done explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A `ContentProvider` doesn't need `android:syncable` to its associated `SyncAdapter`.

And you ask:

> Does that mean that if I don't specify android:syncable="true", I can't use the ContentProvider in the SyncAdapter's onPerform?

That's not what it means.

From the doc, `android:syncable` defines

> Whether or not the data under the content provider's control is to be synchronized with data on a server

AFAIK, you can define a `ContentProvider` without a `SyncAdapter` – the opposite is false, see also [What should I use Android AccountManager for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720315/what-should-i-use-android-accountmanager-for/8614699#8614699)